# Eliding of text when multiple lines in qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a text which is displayed in multiple lines and I need elide to happen for a line when the width of the text is exceeded.
Please find the code below that I have now.

Code:

```
Text {
    width: 500
    maximumLineCount: 3
    horizontalAlignment: "AlignHCenter"
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap//"WordWrap"   
    elide:Text.ElideRight
```

text:"Firstline\nstart_kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk_end"
        color: "red"
      }

Now for me on line 1: "First line" appears and on 2nd line the remaining text appears without any eliding effect(i.e complete text is shown).
It appears the following way:
                           "Firstline
start_kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk_end"
I want eliding to happen at 2nd line as it exceeds the width.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you do manual wrapping, you don't need the wordwrap flag. Does it work without?

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#elide-prop): _The text will only elide if maximumLineCount, or height has been set_. You've set the max lines count to 3 so why do you expect the eliding effect on the second line?

Comment: I have updated the question now with more details for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#elide-prop):

> If this property is set to Text.ElideRight, it can be used with
>   wrapped text. The text will only elide if maximumLineCount, or height
>   has been set. If both maximumLineCount and height are set,
>   maximumLineCount will apply unless the lines do not fit in the height
>   allowed.

So the text will elide either if you add second line before, like:

```
text: "First line \nSecond line \nkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"
```

or

if `maximumLineCount` will be set to 2 lines:

```
maximumLineCount: 2
```